# Automate buildozer with windows bat file and ubuntu script

Tags: copy, buildozer

I am trying to automate buildozer with a windows batch file and a ubuntu script.

The batch file first copies main.py and grid.kv file to ubuntu. - this works just fine.

Next, it calls the wsl command line.  - This creates the akp file, except I could never get "run" to work. I am able to manually install the apk (using android app Apk Installer).

Lastly, I want to copy the apk file to my samsung tab4. - This fails with an error

['''
\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\danm9\bin\grid-0.1-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
The system cannot find the path specified.
0 file(s) copied.
''']

I am able to copy the apk file to the tablet using explorer but the problem seems to be not knowing how to refer to the tablet in the copy command. The receiving directory is what I get when I use "copy address as text" "This PC\Dan Moormann (SM-T530NU)\Tablet\Download" in explorer.

If I was able to get "deploy run" to work, I wouldn't need to copy or install the apk, as it would already be on the tablet, ready to go.

I also tried to use adb push with the same result.

### Batch file

```
    copy c:\Users\danm9\grid\main.py \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\danm9
    copy c:\Users\danm9\grid\grid.kv \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\danm9*
    C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -e bash -lic "cd /home/danm9; sh dbz.sh; exec bash"
    pause
    copy \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\danm9\bin\*.apk "This PC\Dan Moormann (SM-    T530NU)\Tablet\Download"
```

### Script file

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "running dbz.sh"
    buildozer android debug deploy run 
    echo "done"
```